# Vue.js $ref not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to dynamically set the padding of an element using inline styles, based on the height of the parent. For this I am using:

```
<div class="stock-rating positive" ref="stockRating">
    <div class="stock-rating-start-end" v-bind:style="{ paddingTop: paddingTop }">
        <div>{{ rating.value_start }}</div>
        <div>to</div>
        <div>{{ rating.value_end }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`paddingTop` will be a computed property. However, before I compute it, I have to actually access the $ref of the parent element (`stockRating`). But, it is not found in the computed property, even though the $refs object looks to contain it.

```
paddingTop : function(){
    console.log(this.$refs);
    console.log(this.$refs.stockRating);
    /*computation here*/
}
```

The `console.log` output is:

[image]

Why is `this.$refs.stockRating` undefined if `this.$refs` has the `stockRating` property, and I see it contains the correct elements as well? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well your $refs.stockRating is defined AND exists but it will not exists until the component is mounted as explained [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-this-refs-key-returns-undefined-when-it-really-is/1226).
I didn't try it but I guess that if you try to `console.log` your `$refs.stockRating`inside the mounted(){} component property it should not be empty

Comment: I just tried it inside `mounted` and the output is the same.

Comment: That's weird since when the component is mounted the dom is rendered at this point, maybe try adding a flag as @ightmyfire suggested then

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell vue that DOM is ready and component was mounted.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    itemRef() {
      console.log(this.$refs.item)
      return this.ready ? this.$refs.item : false
    }
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      ready: false
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.ready = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div ref="item" class="item">
    {{itemRef}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But even if I put the `console.log` inside `mounted`, I get the same result...could it be something else?